# Humanizer gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set up the apparently simple [Humanizer](https://github.com/kiskolabs/humanizer) gem, but I'm clearly doing something wrong, as messages get sent regardless of the correct answer.

My message method contains:

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend ActiveModel::Naming

attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :humanizer_answer, :presence => true
validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

include Humanizer
require_human_on :create
```

and in my form:

```
<%= form.label :humanizer_answer, @message.humanizer_question %>
<%= form.text_field :humanizer_answer %>
<%= form.hidden_field :humanizer_question_id %>
```

What am i doing wrong? It looks so simple...

Answer (score 3):

Humanizer do not work on non-ActiveRecord models